# Исчезают объекты с формы во время запуска

Tags: ios, swift

Добавил на MainStoryBoard Label, TextField и Button.

Скомпоновал их.

Когда запускаю приложение в симуляторе в течении пары секунд видны и Label, и TextField, и Button. Но буквально через две секунды после запуска они исчезают и все что я вижу - просто белый фон.

Что делать?

---

Как это выглядит у меня (справа - как должно быть, а в симуляторе - что получилось):

[image: Вот скрин того, что должно быть и что получается]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скрину, Вы поместили элементы на `LaunchScreen`. Он появляется на короткое время при запуске приложения и используется, как правило, показать какой-то логотип/картинку/еще чего, не для взаимодействия.

Перейдите на `Main.storyboard` и начинайте создавать интерфейс там.